# Why do i get a Segmentation fault in C?

Tags: c, gcc

I have been learning about structures in C and when i try to execute this code i get a Segmentation fault.

```
struct hero {
    char *name;
    struct hero_properties *prop;
};

struct hero_properties {
    int damage;
    int health;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct hero pudje;

    define_hero_name(&pudje, "pudje");
    set_hero_properties(&pudje, 65, 760);
    get_hero_info(&pudje);

    return 0;
}

void set_hero_properties(struct hero *name, int damage, int health)
{
    name->prop->damage = damage;
    name->prop->health = health;
}

void define_hero_name(struct hero *name, char *d_name)
{
    name->name = d_name;
}

void get_hero_info(struct hero *name)
{
    printf("%s characteristics:\n", name->name);
    printf("damage: %d\n", name->prop->damage);
    printf("health: %d\n", name->prop->health);
}
```

As i realize it the fault in that expression, but why?

```
name->prop->damage = damage;
name->prop->health = health;
```

Comment: You never assign anything to `prop` so it points to wherever and undefined behaviour ensues. Turn your compiler's warnings and errors to the max. Also start using a debugger, it will show you what's going on.

Comment: but when I have debugged this in gdb by
    print name->prop->damage 
it was no error and I have seen a right result

Comment: Your `define_hero_name` function also doesn't do what you think it does. It does not copy the name. Instead, it will only copy a pointer to the name. Depending on your use in your game later on, reading this name back might also lead to a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that the `hero` struct only keeps a pointer to the `hero_properties` struct. A pointer in it self does not give you an actual memory to write the properties to. Since there is a strong connection between the hero and its properties, you probably want the `hero_properties` struct to be part of the `hero`struct. However, that requires that the `hero_properties` struct is defined before the `hero`:

```
struct hero_properties {
    int damage;
    int health;
};

struct hero {
    char *name;
    struct hero_properties prop;
};
```

Then you have to access the elements with dot notation, rather than arrows:

```
name->prop.damage = damage;
```

Comment: thx for that dude :). However is it possible to do that `hero_properties` to be after `hero` ?

Comment: @Devart No, C doesn't know what a `struct hero_properties` is until you declare it. You will get an error message saying `error: field 'prop' has incomplete type`.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference to help you with debugging and so you do not have to wait for SO replies, you should consider compiling with `gcc -g -o YourExecutableName NameOfYourFileToCompile.c -Wall`, which will compile in debugging mode and show you all compiler warnings, then you can run through with a debugger of your choice which should show exactly which line causes the segfault.

Anyway, as Sami pointed out in the comments, the issue is that you never point the `hero.prop` pointer to a `hero_properties` structure, and as such, when you attempt to access `name->prop->damage`, you are casting and dereferencing memory that you have not actually assigned to anything; hence the segmentation fault. For your particular issue, you can fix this by saying:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct hero pudje;
    struct hero_properties props; // allocates an instance of hero_properties to the stack
    pudje.prop = &props; // provides hero.prop with the pointer to that instance of the structure

    define_hero_name(&pudje, "pudje");
    set_hero_properties(&pudje, 65, 760);
    get_hero_info(&pudje);

    return 0;
}
```